# How to initiate a date picker when template is loaded remotely from controller action

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, javascript

I have a controller action which returns JSON with a rendered template.  This template uses date picker form fields.  How can the date picker JS be initialized since the html is returned through JSON. I would have thought since the date picker field includes the necessary JS within {%js%} tag during template render it would be initialized. Could it be the timing of render vs adding the template html to the DOM? (Craft 3)

```
$view = $this->getView();

$html = $view->renderTemplate('_modal',['values' => $values, 'siteId' => $siteId]);
$headHtml = $view->getHeadHtml();

return $this->asJson(['html' => $html, 'headHtml' => $headHtml]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your controller returns json you'll probably have a Javascript function that calls this controller so you can initialize it at the moment you receive the html.

Besides that you can as well include Javascript in your `Craft::$app->getView()->registerJs` [class](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-web-view.html#registerJs()-detail).

Comment: So the JS included in the DatePicker field macro won't be executed therefore I will need to initialize either in the JS function or using `getView()->registerJs`?